# Is it cost efficient for an empty interface to extends another interface? TS

Tags: typescript

i encounter the following dilema.

```
interface ICodeDescription {
    codigo: string;
    descripcion: string;
}

export interface IIvaOptions extends ICodeDescription { }
export interface IIIBBCodes extends ICodeDescription { }
export interface IPersonType extends ICodeDescription { }
```

Is this approach worth the typings? Taking in account the memory use in a big scenario. Or should i just use `ICodeDescription` to type everything?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Interfaces doesn't exist in javascript. They only exist at compile time. So i came to the conclusion that this approach is worth the typings, taking in accounts that i will have cleaner code and the "slow" will only occur when compiling.

Comment: In Javascript, interfaces don't exist anymore, so once compiled, these have exactly zero effect on the final result. At most, that would affect the compilation stage, and I doubt such declarations can have any significant effect on the compiler resource usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, types only exist at compile time. They are not present in the generated EcmaScript code, and hence can not incur any runtime cost.

Also, the memory use of an additional declaration in the typescript compiler is probably about 100 bytes. You would need need to write millions of such declarations to notice a performance difference in the compiler.